# Ubuntu touch - How to open .doc word documents in googlemail

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm using Ubuntu touch on my MX4 and I can't open up .doc files in googlemail.

When I try to open one it gives the following error message :

> Sorry, there aren't currently any apps installed that can handle this
>   type of content

Can you suggest an app that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

[Document Viewer](https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.docviewer) can open doc files, but only latest few versions. If you already have Document Viewer which doesn't work, try updating it first.